# How do I test that something is valid for all elements in a map?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have the following things in my application:

```hs
newtype User = User Text
newtype Counts = Counts (Map User Int)

subjectUnderTest :: Counts -> Text
```

An example of correct output would be

```
> subjectUnderTest $ fromList [(User "foo", 4), (User "bar", 4), (User "qux", 2)]
"4: foo, bar\n2: qux"
```

I would like to write property-based tests that verify things like "all users are represented in the output", "all counts are represented in the output" and "all users are on the same line as their corresponding count". In common for these properties is that the wording of them starts with "all ..."

**How do I write a property that verifies that something is valid for each element in the `Map`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that this question is only a simplified representation of something more complex, so here's a couple of things strategies to consider:

## Split up the functionality

It looks like `subjectUnderTest` does two unrelated things:

1. It groups the values in the map by value, instead of by key.
2. It formats, or pretty-prints, the inverted map.

If you can split up the functionality into those two steps, they're easier to test in in isolation.

The first step, you can make parametrically polymorphic. Instead of testing a function with the type `Counts -> Text`, consider testing a function with the type `Eq b => Map a b -> [(b, [a])]`. Property-based testing is easier with parametric polymorphism, because [you get certain properties for free](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/07/09/typing-and-testing-problem-23). For example, you can be sure that the values in the output can only come from the input, because there's no way to conjure `a` and `b` values out of thin air.

You're still going to have to write tests for the properties you ask about. Write a function with a type like `Eq b => Map a b -> Testable`. If you want to test that all the values are there, pull them out of the map and make list of them. Sort the list and `nub` it. It's now a `[b]` value. That's your expected output.

Now call your function. It returns something like `[(b, [a])]`. Map it using `fst`, sort and `nub` it. That list should be equal to your expected output.

For the next step (pretty-printing), see the next section.

## Roundtrips

When you want to property-base pretty-printing, the easiest approach is usually to bite the bullet and also write a parser. The printer and the parser should be the dual of each other, so if you have a function `MyType -> String`, your should have a parser with the type `String -> Maybe MyType`.

You can now write a general property like `MyType -> Testable`. It takes as input a value of `MyType` (let's call it `expected`). You now produce a value (let's call it `actual`) as `actual = parse $ print expected`. You can now verify that `Just expected === actual`.

If the particular `String` format is important, I'd follow it up with a few actual examples, using [good old parametrised tests](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/04/30/parametrised-unit-tests-in-haskell).

Just because you're doing property-based testing doesn't mean that a 'normal' unit test can't be useful as well.

---

## Example

Here's a simple example of what I meant above. Assume that

```
invertMap :: (Ord b, Eq b) => Map a b -> [(b, [a])]
```

you can define one of the properties as:

```
allValuesAreNowKeys :: (Show a, Ord a) => Map k a -> Property
allValuesAreNowKeys m =
  let expected = nub $ sort $ Map.elems m
      actual = invertMap m
  in expected === nub (sort $ fmap fst actual)
```

Since this property is still parametrically polymorphic, you'll have to add it to your test suite with a particular type, e.g.:

```
tests = [
  testGroup "Sorting Group 1" [
    testProperty "all values are now keys" (allValuesAreNowKeys :: Map String Int -> Property)]]
```

There are prettier ways to define lists of properties; that one is just the template used by the *quickcheck-test-framework* Stack template...

Comment: The `containers` package has a module of list utilities consisting mostly if not entirely of more-efficient variations on `nub`.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer!

The question is actually surprisingly close to the problem I'm actually after solving - I've changed a few names, and the input strings are obviously made up, but otherwise both the type and the output format is the exact problem I'm working on. Does that change any part of your answer? 

I managed to come up with some hack creating a `[Expectation]` and using `conjoin` to make it a `Expectation` (it turns out `Expectation` is a monoid!), which seems to test the things I want, but gives awful error messages when tests fail. I will give your approach a spin!

Comment: @TomasAschan FWIW I've added an example.